# Nestjs: Type does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, document

I'm getting `Type 'BranchesDocument' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.` error message. Can anyone please tell what is the mistake in my code?

**branches.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {InjectModel} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {Model} from 'mongoose';
import {BranchesDocument} from './branches.schema';

@Injectable()
export class BranchesService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('Branches') private branchesModel: Model<BranchesDocument>) {}
}
```

**branches.schema.ts**

```
import {Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {IBranches} from './branches.interface';

export type BranchesDocument = BranchDetails & Document;

@Schema()
export class BranchDetails implements IBranches {
  @Prop()
  profileId: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  location: string;
}

export const BranchesSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(BranchDetails);
```

branches.interface.ts

```
export interface IBranches {
  profileId: string;
  name: string;
  location: string;
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfAm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export `Document` from `mongoose` then you will have to extend `IBranches` interface to `Document`. Like below -

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IBranches extends Document{
  profileId: string;
  name: string;
  location: string;
}
```

Comment: A couple of things you can try - 1) In your services import Branches from branches.interface.ts. 2) you need to make some changes to schema.ts too. You can follow this github repo of mine https://github.com/sprakash57/mow-a-lawn-api for reference purposes. It is fully working. Let me know if you need help.